# c# windows form System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#

I am trying to write c # code that automates the process of filling out Word templates. I use DataGridView because I don't know how many types of elements I need to replace. Upon completion of work, it throws an error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)" thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace Anya_v_0._8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //-------------------struct---------------------//
    public struct name
    {
        public string teg;
        public string change;

        public name(String _teg, string _change)
        {
            teg = _teg;
            change = _change;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------//
    List<name> names = new List<name>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //-------------------table------------//
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Тэг", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Название", typeof(string));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(names[i].teg, names[i].change);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        //-------------------------------//



    }


    private void click_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        String vhod = inputBox.Text;
        String uhod = outputBox.Text;
        
       
            var wordApp = new Word.Application();
            wordApp.Visible = false;
            
            var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(vhod);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {              
                object a = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].ToString();
                object b = dataGridView1.Rows[i+1].Cells[j].ToString();
                ReplaceWordStub(a, b, wordDocument);
                    
            }
            }
            wordDocument.SaveAs(uhod);
           
        

    }

    private void ReplaceWordStub(object stubToReplace, object text, Word.Document wordDocument)
    {
       
            var range = wordDocument.Content;
            range.Find.ClearFormatting();
            range.Find.Execute(FindText: stubToReplace, ReplaceWith: text);
        
    }
    public void inputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution needs to have the word installed to work, you could use [OpenXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1) instead.

But considering you want to keep this dependency on Word, check if the **Remote Procedure Call** is started and running on your windows services